# Setting a property using win32com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to create a bunch of Outlook rules automatically. I'm using Python 2.7, win32com, and Outlook 2007. To do this I must create a new Rule object and specify a folder for its move action. However, I can't set the Folder property successfully -- it just stays None despite me giving an object of the right type.

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as const

o = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
rules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() 

rule = rules.Create("Python rule test", const.olRuleReceive) 
condition = rule.Conditions.MessageHeader 
condition.Text = ('Foo', 'Bar')
condition.Enabled = True

root_folder = o.GetNamespace('MAPI').Folders.Item(1)
foo_folder = root_folder.Folders['Notifications'].Folders['Foo']

move = rule.Actions.MoveToFolder
print foo_folder
print move.Folder
move.Folder = foo_folder
print move.Folder

# move.Enabled = True
# rules.Save()
```

Prints

```
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library.MAPIFolder instance at 0x51634584>
None
None
```

I've looked at the code generated by `makepy` when using win32com in non-dynamic mode. The class `_MoveOrCopyRuleAction` has an entry for `'Folder'` in its `_prop_map_put_` dict, but other than that I'm stumped.

Comment: I've got this working with IronPython. I needed to use: Outlook._MoveOrCopyRuleAction.Folder.SetValue(rule.Actions.MoveToFolder, folder). Nonetheless I'd still like to see a win32com answer.

Comment: I get an error object has no attribute 'DefaultStore' when running the above.  Am I missing a rules store?  WHat is one ? Also does the SetFolder() appraoch in win32com work on the objects IronPython uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `comtypes.client` instead of `win32com.client` you can do:

```
import comtypes.client

o = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
rules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() 

rule = rules.Create("Python rule test", 0 ) # 0 is the value for the parameter olRuleReceive
condition = rule.Conditions.Subject # I guess MessageHeader works too
condition.Text = ('Foo', 'Bar')
condition.Enabled = True

root_folder = o.GetNamespace('MAPI').Folders.Item(1)
foo_folder = root_folder.Folders['Notifications'].Folders['Foo']

move = rule.Actions.MoveToFolder
move.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Enabled(True) # Need this line otherwise 
                                                    # the folder is not set in outlook
move.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Folder(foo_folder) # set the destination folder

rules.Save() # to save it in Outlook
```

I know it's not with win32com.client, but not with IronPython either!

Comment: Any idea on how to do this from a second account? In other words, how to switch to a different account, for example session.accounts[2]

Comment: @usr unfortunately, I don't know like this and I don't have the right set up on my computer aymore to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try SetFolder()

I think from a cursory reading of your code try SetFolder(move, foo_folder)

win32com does some amazing magic but at times COM objects just defeat it. 
when the object cannot follow the pythonic convention, behind the scenes a setter and getter is created of form  Set{name} Get{name}

see: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.windows/3231
NB - Mark Hammonds how to debug com is priceless - this stuff is just hidden in usegroups ...

Comment: SetFolder on which object? `print move.SetFolder` raises an AttributeError