# "Member not found." error using win32com

Tags: python, vba, com, win32com

I'm having issues accessing a COM object using the Python win32com module, which I don't have when using VBA. See usage/error below. The other parts of the object are functioning OK, but I can't get any of the parameters out of the ResultSet object.

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> Aquator = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Aquator.Application")
>>> db = Aquator.LoadDatabase(r"D:\Shared", "AquatorExcel.mdb")
>>> project = Aquator.LoadProject(db, "A simple model", False, False)
>>>
>>> project.ModelRunStart()
<win32com.gen_py.Aquator Water Resource Simulation._ModelRun instance at 0x15264
824>
>>> Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Count
1
>>> Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Item(1).ResultSet
<win32com.gen_py.Aquator Water Resource Simulation._IResultSet instance at 0x149
19000>
>>> Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Item(1).ResultSet.Cost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Pythonxy\Pythonxy 2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32c
om\client\__init__.py", line 463, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Pythonxy\Pythonxy 2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32c
om\client\__init__.py", line 456, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

The equivalent code in the VBA editor within the application functions correctly, returning a float:

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Item(1).ResultSet.Cost
End Sub
```

As far as I can tell, the EnsureDispatch command has done it's job correctly, and recognises the property (along with others, also inaccessible):

```
>>> Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Item(1).ResultSet._prop_map_get_.keys()
['WaterBalanceMl', 'RunDate', 'Parameters', 'DoublePrecision', 'WarningCount', '
FinishDate', 'AmountLost', 'SinglePrecision', 'Status', 'StartDate', 'Descriptio
n', 'AmountLeaked', 'FailureCount', 'AmountAdded', 'ErrorCount', 'AmountStored',
 'Name', 'WaterBalancePercent', 'InfoValueList', 'Results', 'States', 'Cost', 'A
mountRemoved', 'Sequences', 'Duration', 'InfoNameList', 'RunTime']
>>> Aquator.ActiveProject.ModelRuns.Item(1).ResultSet.meh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Pythonxy\Pythonxy 2.7\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32c
om\client\__init__.py", line 462, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr
))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Aquator Water Resource Simulation._IResultSet
instance at 0x15175888>' object has no attribute 'meh'
```

I have tried using .GetCost() (a la [Setting a property using win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089496/setting-a-property-using-win32com)), to no avail ("object has no attribute...").

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is with the win32com module. The equivilent code using the comtypes module functions correctly:

```
>>> from comtypes.client import CreateObject
>>> Aquator = CreateObject("Aquator.Application")
>>> Database = Aquator.LoadDatabase(r"D:\Shared", "AquatorExcel.mdb")
>>> Project = Aquator.LoadProject(Database, "A simple project", False, False)
>>> ModelRun = Project.ModelRunStart()
>>> print ModelRun.ResultSet.Cost
133432.20
```