# Writing ADODB Recordset to Pivot Cache With Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am working on a project where I am converting some VBA code to Python, in order to have Python interact with Excel in much the same way VBA would. In this particular case, I am utilizing the `win32com` library to have Python extract data from an Oracle Database via an ADODB Connection and write the resulting recordset directly to a pivot cache. I.e. creating a pivot table with data from an external source.

```
import win32com.client

Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
win32c = win32com.client.constants

# Create and Open Connection
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
DSN = 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=localhost:1521/XEPDB1; User Id=system; Password=password;'
conn.Open(DSN)

# Create Excel File
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

# Create Recordset
RS = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
RS.Open('SELECT * FROM employees', conn, 1, 3)

# Create Pivot Cache
PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlExternal, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion15)

# Write Recordset to Pivot Cache
PivotCache.Recordset = RS # <~~ This is where it breaks!

# Create Pivot Table
Pivot = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Sheet1.Cells(2, 2), TableName:='Python Test Pivot', DefaultVersion:=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion15)

# Close Connection
RS.Close()
conn.Close()

# View Excel
Excel.Visible = 1
```

I am successful in extracting the data via ADODB and creating an Excel file, but when I try to write the resulting recordset to the pivot cache by setting `PivotCache.Recordset = RS`, I get the following error.

```
[Running] venv\Scripts\python.exe "c:\Project\Test\debug_file_test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Project\Test\debug_file_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    PivotCache.Recordset = RS # <~~ This is where it breaks!
  File "c:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 482, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'No such interface supported\r\n', None, 0, -2146827284), None)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.674 seconds
```

Can anybody shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is it the same problem as [Setting a property using win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089496)? Hinting at `SetRecordset`

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't seen `comtypes.client` before. I will have a look at it when I get back to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to the issue, and want to post an answer for anyone who may come across this question at some point.

Instead of creating the recordset by `Recordset.Open()` I tried using the command object and create the recordset by `cmd.Execute()`. As it turns out that `Execute` returns a tuple, I had to pass `cmd.Execute()[0]` to the recordset in order to make it work.

This doesn't answer why my initial code doesn't work, but it does provide an answer for ***how to write an ADODB recordset to a PivotCache with Python***.

```
import win32com.client

#Initiate Excel Application
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
win32c = win32com.client.constants

# Create and Open Connection
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
cmd = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Command')
DSN = 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=localhost:1521/XEPDB1; User Id=system; Password=password;'
conn.Open(DSN)

# Define Command Properties
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.ActiveConnection.CursorLocation = win32c.adUseClient
cmd.CommandType = win32c.adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM employees'

# Create Excel File
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

# Create Recordset
RS = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Recordset')
RS = cmd.Execute()[0]

# Create Pivot Cache
PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlExternal, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion15)
PivotCache.Recordset = RS

# Create Pivot Table
Pivot = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Sheet1.Cells(2, 2), TableName:='Python Test Pivot', DefaultVersion:=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion15)

# Close Connection
RS.Close()
conn.Close()

# View Excel
Excel.Visible = 1
```

**Update**

As hinted by @Parfait the code above also works if `RS = cmd.Execute()[0]` is replaced by

```
RS.Open(cmd)
```

Which I actually prefer because that secures alignment between the VB syntax and the Python syntax.

Comment: Interesting! How about running example in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.recordset) using your original  `Recordset.Open` method but with command object: `RS.Open(cmd,  conn, 1, 3)`.

Comment: I didn't think about that solution. That works too, If I only pass `cmd` to the command object: `RS.Open(cmd)`