# Using python and win32com to write outlook rules

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, rules

I've been trying really hard to make it work in python 3.7 and outlook 365.  A related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089496/setting-a-property-using-win32com) and the VBA documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/rules/create-a-rule-to-move-specific-e-mails-to-a-folder). I can't manage to solve it.

Everything in the code is working fine, except the two lines commented out in the code.

Please, help!

```
import win32com.client as win32

o = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

musterman = o.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders['musterman@outlook.at']

dest_folder = musterman.Folders["Posteingang"].Folders["Ich"]
colRules = o.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
oRule = colRules.Create("New Rule", 0)

oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From
oFromCondition.Enabled = True
oFromCondition.Recipients.Add("john@email.com")
oFromCondition.Recipients.ResolveAll

oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
oMoveRuleAction.Enabled = True                 #not working
oMoveRuleAction.Folder = dest_folder           #not working

colRules.Save()
```

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OneDrive/Projekte/coding/python - working_with_outlook/scrapbookIII.py", line 21, in <module>
    colRules.Save()
  File "<COMObject GetRules>", line 2, in Save
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Mindestens eine Regel kann aufgrund von ungültigen Aktionen oder Bedingungen nicht gespeichert werden.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are you getting an error? Or is the folder simply not set when you view the rules later?

Comment: Sorry, Dmitry, and thank you for pointing that out. The rule is created in outlook, the rule has a name and a condition, but the part of the rule about a destination folder is missing. I edited the question with these details.

Comment: Does it work if you point the rule to a folder in the default store (where you are creating the rule)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - Thanks for the attention! Actually, i do get an error with the code above. I just listed in the question. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: So, is the folder in question from a different store? Does it work with a folder from the primary store?

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same error when I run it with a folder from the primary store.

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko. The code doesnt work with a folder from the primary store. . .