# pywin32 - get cell Address in R1C1 format

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

I am working with pywin32 and trying to get the R1C1 address of a specific cell. In VBA, you can use `Range.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`.

However, it appears that in pywin32, using `Range.Address` is not a method that allows for parameters, but instead is a property that just returns the string in the A1-style.

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('my_workbook.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

c = sht.Range("A1")
c.Address
# returns "$A$1"

c.Address(ReferenceStyle=-4150)
# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @lifeisstillgood in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089496/setting-a-property-using-win32com) gives a steer.

`win32com` gets around the issue of `Property` calls that take parameters (ie really are `Methods` in disguise) by quietly generating Get and/or Set methods.

The exact method will depend on how the Excel object is created.

1. Using `Dispatch()` and late-binding. Here you seem to need to add the default parameters to the call, in the order [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address).

```
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    ...
    c.GetAddress(True,True,-4150)
```

2. Using `EnsureDispatch()` and early-binding. Here `win32com` generates Python wrappers, which allows the named parameters, and also generates the Excel constants.

```
    xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    ...
    c.GetAddress(ReferenceStyle=win32com.client.constants.xlR1C1)
```

If you look in the `Range.py` wrapper, this function has been generated:

```
# The method GetAddress is actually a property, but must be used as a method to correctly pass the arguments
def GetAddress(self, RowAbsolute=defaultNamedNotOptArg, ColumnAbsolute=defaultNamedNotOptArg, ReferenceStyle=1, External=defaultNamedOptArg, RelativeTo=defaultNamedOptArg):
    # Result is a Unicode object
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(236, LCID, 2, (8, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17)),RowAbsolute
                , ColumnAbsolute, ReferenceStyle, External, RelativeTo)
```